# Pickle not writing to file and program terminates after pickle.dump()

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I am trying to write a program that initializes a dictionary with web scraping, and then serializes the dictionary using pickle so that the program doesn't need to scrape after the first time it is run. My issue is that after calling `pickle.dump(someDict, dictFile)`, no data is written to the file and the program actually terminates. The code I am using is below:

```
if not Path(getcwd() + "\\dic.pickle").is_file():
    someDict = funcToScrapeDict()
    with open("dic.pickle", "wb") as dic_file:
        pickle.dump(someDict, dic_file)
else:
    with open("dic.pickle", "rb") as dic_file:
        someDict = pickle.load(dic_file)
```

`<<lots more code here processing someDict>>`

So if the pickle file already exists it will just jump to unpickling.

I know that my scraping function works inside the loop because I test printed it immediately before calling `pickle.dump(someDict, dic_file)`, so termination happens immediately after that call with no bytes written to file (though the file is created) and no error messages.

I am on Windows 10 using python 3.7.1

I also increased recursion limit because of a previous runtime error and tried using absolute paths with no luck.

[EDIT] Also worth noting that I tried this exact implementation outside of the scope of my problem with just a manually created dictionary of equal size (280) and it worked fine.

Comment: Could you please present a sample of someDict for inspection?

Comment: No famous last words (errors/stacktrace) of your program?

Comment: Both keys and values are strings. So the dictionary would be something like `someDict = {"Acll": "AACCGT", "Hndll": "AATATT", ...}` with a bunch more like that

Comment: Nope, no errors/stacktrace. Just plain exits. When I run it a second time I get an EOF error which is expected since nothing is being written the first time.